# Why Is the .tagged Method of Pytumblr Returning Random Posts

Tags: python, pytumblr

When I use the `.tagged` method in the pytumblr library, the API seems to return random posts instead of the most recent 20. How can I actually get the 20 most recent posts in a tag? Here is the code I am using:

```py
import pytumblr

client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
    'keys',
    'keys',
    'keys',
    'keys'
)

response = client.tagged("art")

for i in response:
    print(i['timestamp'])
    print(i['post_url'])
```

and here is the output:

```
1446792788
https://blue-voids.tumblr.com/post/132651730803/keliy-anderson-staley
1446644341
https://joquz.tumblr.com/post/132535555014/upriverdownriver
1446662412
https://www.bloggingisoverrated.com/post/132548942098/20-year-old-photographer-mehran-djojans-dreamy
1446712429
https://redlipstickresurrected.tumblr.com/post/132591515330/johan-barrios-colombian-b-1982-barranquilla
1446751862
https://lafilleblanc.tumblr.com/post/132615388566/guido-lafigliola-generative-landscape-artist-found
1434105061
https://theearofvangogh.dahdash.com/post/121342231383
1446632264
https://emmanuelcorreia.tumblr.com/post/132529756954/this-is-part-of-a-serie-of-flying-houses-i-am
1446625007
https://lafilleblanc.tumblr.com/post/132526943541/paolo-icaro-scolpire1982-tensioni-2014-sulla
1446643231
https://crossconnectmag.tumblr.com/post/132534908579
1443830605
https://opticallyaddicted.tumblr.com/post/130367056210/land-of-the-giants-project-for-iceland-this
1446214803
https://lafilleblanc.tumblr.com/post/132211226526/pierre-le-hors-fireworks-studies-2009-via
1446660018
https://www.bloggingisoverrated.com/post/132546950906/classical-paintings-in-modern-world-part-ii
1388050080
https://contemporary-art-blog.tumblr.com/post/71189714369
1446565343
https://marklovejoydotcom.tumblr.com/post/132475934938/5306b
1446564146
https://dromik.tumblr.com/post/132475030816/joachim-bandau-25-1-2011-2010
1445513429
https://joquz.tumblr.com/post/131679207049/wall-of-bicycles
1446509606
https://joquz.tumblr.com/post/132437531889/jeffrey-austin
1446487994
https://thisisnthappiness.com/post/132416963504/home-alone-manuel-pita
1446526230
https://opticallyaddicted.tumblr.com/post/132453831500/jeffrey-michael-austin-is-an-artistsculptor-and
1435292143
https://hardsci-fi.tumblr.com/post/122477395233/mining-facility-by-atelier-olschinsky

Process finished with exit code 0
```

These are posts mostly from 2015 and some are months apart.

I tried using the before parameter with the current unix timestamp, but that gave the same results. I also tried using the `.posts` method to get recent posts from blogs who often post in the art tag and that was able to return posts that `.tagged` couldn't. I also tried other tags with the `.tagged` method which gave similar results.